# How to directly call setter of an object's parent class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

**TLDR;** How to directly call setter of an object's parent class without invoking the child's setter outside of both the parent and child class?

---

I know that if the solution exists, it may be very hacky/magic-like, but I don't mind. Here's the scenario:

- `Parent` is class from a 3rd party library so I can't change this code at all.
- `Child` is a class from my codebase, but I'd like to keep the magic code outside of it, as the `Prop` class may be use with different "`Child`" classes.
- `Prop` is the class where the magic code may reside if necessary.

I need to access the `Parent`'s setter of `x` via a `Child` object without invoking the setter of `x` of the `Child`.

Is it even possible?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this._x = 255;
  }
  set x(v) {
    console.log("Calling Parent setter");
    this._x = v;
  }
  get x() {
    console.log("Calling Parent getter");
    return this._x;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.prop = new Prop(this);
  }

  set x(v) {
    console.log("AVOID! Calling Child setter");
    super.x = v;
    // Shennanigans I don't want to run
  }

  get x() {
    console.log("Calling Child getter");
    return super.x;
  }
}

class Prop {
  constructor(child) {
    this.child = child;
  }
  setX() {
    const parent = this.child; // Not sure what to do here.
    const old = parent.x;
    parent.x = 0;
    console.log(`parent.x changed from ${old} to ${parent.x}`);
  }
}

const child = new Child();
child.prop.setX();
```

Comment: @Shilly `this.child.super.x = 0;` results in an error, AFAIK you can't use `super` outside the child class

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't knew that yet. ( never tried due to not encountering this issue before. )

Comment: This seems like a bad design to me. Why should `Prop` know anything about the fact that `this.child` extends a specific class? If this is something that should be known, then doing composition (and exposing the composed value) as Bergi suggests seems more reasonable.

Comment: @FelixKling It's adding a new behaviour to a certain set of classes by composition (we want to avoid multiple inheritance) that are known to have certain properties. There's only one `Prop` class, but many `Child` classes, so it makes sense to have the prop class and then just include it in the `Child` classes. Also, we need to inherit `Child` classes from `Parent` because `Parent` already exposes a good chunk of API and it would be inefficient to re-implement it in every `Child` class. But I agree that this is not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Reflect.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set) is here to your rescue! It does allow to pass the receiver separately:

```
setX() {
  Reflect.set(Parent.prototype, "x", 0, this.child); // invokes the Parent.protype.x setter
}
```

Alternatives would be `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Parent.prototype, "x").set.call(this.child, 0)` or just `this.child._x = 0` (if you don't need to run the setter code).

---

So while it is possible, I would recommend to reconsider your design. Maybe inheritance is the wrong approach here, and you should use composition instead of `extends Parent`:

```
class Child {
  constructor() {
    this.val = new Parent();
  }

  set x(v) {
    … // Shenanigans
    this.val.x = v;
  }

  get x() {
    return this.val.x;
  }

  // (without the Prop helper class for simplicity)
  setX(v) {
    // without shenanigans
    this.val.x = v;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a heaven-sent. Thank you, it works like charm. You deserve all the internet points and more. :D